# How to fetch data from database in Magento with LIKE keyword?

Tags: php, magento

I want a select query which fetch the data from database with "like" keyword
eg.

```
select product name, image , description
from table where product name LIKE "'.$name'";
```

I want it in Magento that how to fetch this fields from database in Magento. My existing query is:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
    WHERE entity_type_id = (
        SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
    )
";
```

Now the join query is :-

```
<?php
$sql = " 
       SELECT p.entity_id , pv.value as name , pt.value as description , GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT ( cp.category_id ) SEPARATOR ', ') as categories , GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT (pm.value) SEPARATOR ', ') as imagesPath 
       FROM catalog_product_entity as p
       INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar as pv on pv.entity_id = p.entity_id  and   pv.attribute_id = 71
       INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_text as pt on pt.entity_id = p.entity_id and pt.attribute_id = 72
       INNER JOIN catalog_category_product as cp on cp.product_id = p.entity_id
       LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery as pm on pm.entity_id = p.entity_id and pm.attribute_id = 88
       GROUP BY cp.product_id , pm.entity_id " ;

   foreach($readConnection->fetchAll($sql) as $orders)
   {
   ?>   
      <?php echo $orders['name']; ?>
      <?php echo $orders['description']; ?>

 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: That looks like SQL with some PHP in the middle of it. Assuming you want to do this in PHP, what PHP do you have so far? What have you tried, and what problem are you having with it? Note you will probably want to use parameter binding - it looks like you would have a SQL injection vulnerability in your example.

Comment: First of all thanks for correcting me :) and you are right this is a query of sql with php variable and i don't want to do this in php, i just want this query in Magento that how to fetch data from database with like clause. I have a query of Magento which fetch all the product names from database but i can't understand  that where should i put the like clause in that query. The query is :

Comment: $sql = "SELECT `value`
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') 
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')) ";

Comment: I have added that into your question. Would you spend a couple of moments reformatting it (with newlines) so that it is readable?

Comment: Also into the question, please add whether you can use parameter binding - do you have MySQLi or PDO/mysql available? Or is there a database library?

Comment: Oh thank you so much you have solved my problem upto 80% I should use the joins in my query, and i use MySQLi

Comment: I have added a join query which is working perfect
now I want to put a ' LIKE '  clause in that query 
thank you so much Halfer

Comment: What type is `$readConnection`? Is that a MySQLi instance, or a Magento class?

Comment: $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
it is a variable which i have created on the top of the page.

Comment: What sort of class is it an instance of?

Comment: By default, Magento connects automatically to it's database and provide two separate resources which we can use to access data: core_read and core_write.Core_read is for reading from the database while core_write is for writing to the database.

Comment: OK. Take [a look here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103032/how-to-run-direct-sql-query-on-magento-and-bind-where-in-params) on how to do parameter binding with placeholders - and then it is just a question of adding `WHERE x = :value` and binding onto `:value` in the `query()` method.

Comment: Thanks Halfer for your help. :)

Comment: If you have solved it, please add an answer below, thanks.

Comment: i have added the correct code thanks ..
and still i'm searching for that how to get an image

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about images - is that maybe a new question?

Comment: hahaha yeah you are right now i'm working on image.. :D

Answer (score 0):

This one is correct code to fetch the name and description of item in LIKE clause 
Thank you so much @Halfer :)

```
$sql = SELECT p.`entity_id`, pv.`value` as name, pt.`value` as description 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` as p
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as pv on pv.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and     pv.`attribute_id` = 71
INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` as pt on pt.`entity_id` = p.`entity_id` and pt.`attribute_id` = 72
Where pv.value LIKE '%hp%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql_jacket = "SELECT entity_id FROM customer_entity where email
like '".$_REQUEST['useremail']."'";
$result_jacket = $conn->query($sql_jacket);
if ($result_jacket->num_rows > 0) 
{    
while($row_jacket = $result_jacket->fetch_assoc())
{
    $result1['user_status']=1;
}
}
```